# Skip going back to direct parent activity when pressed back

Tags: android, android-intent

I have got a small problem in an Android app I am working on :

There are 3 activities namely A , B , C and the invocation is in the following order : 
A -> B -> C. While in C, when I press BACK button, it should go back to A[Instead of the B by default]. And pressing BACK in A will exit the program.

I tried to call an intent from C to A. But in this case the call invocation gets into a loop : 
A -> B -> C -> A since the new activity is pushed on top of the stack. As a result, when BACK is pressed at A, instead of exiting [A is the start], it goes to C and then B and then back to A in a needless circle.

It would be great if someone could give a better way to address this loopy scenario!

Comment: can u paste some code of your's ??

Comment: simply call intent of Activity A on Back Button of C.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Very simple!!
When you are starting the activity C, from B, use B.finish(). Something like this.

```
Intent i = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
B.this.finish();
startActivity(i);
```

This will remove B from the stack!

Answer (score 12):

Probably late, but for people who might find this in a search:
You can add

```
        android:noHistory="true"
```

to your activity B in your AndroidManifest.
This will also avoid that the onActivityResult() method is called in activity B when C returns a result though. I'ts basically like B disappears as soon as you start C.

Comment: I found that nasty line of code in a manifest after picking up someone else's project. It took me hours to notice this innocuous little line of code hiding in the manifest after I spent so long trying different combinations of launching Activities with different Intents (different issue...). I don't recommend this because, as Jess notes, B disappears as soon as you start C... which may hinder your ability to perform any kind of proper handling

Comment: Upvote for the last paragraph! It's a nuance that got me off guard! Just liked @1owk3y  :P

Answer (score 2):

Set a flag for B activity like this

```
private boolean mDestroyActivity = false;
```

set that flag true when you call startActivity C.

for activity B onStop method add checking like this:

```
if (mDestroyActivity) finish();
```

Then when you press back button in C you will jump back to A.

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You can start Activity C with `startActivityForResult()` and inside `onActivityResult()` finish Activity B.

To start Activity C,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
```

And override in Activity B

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == 123){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

And inside Activity C use `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)` before `finish();`

**UPDATE:**

Another way is to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to start Activity A from Activity C.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivitC.this, ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

One more way can be just `finish()` Activity B when you are starting Activity C. So, when you press back on Activity C it will directly move to Activity A as Activity B has already finished.

Answer (score 1):

please set this FLAG before launching a new Activity

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Answer (score 1):

In Manifest file mention in activity tag below value

> android:noHistory="true"

then it will skip the activity

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not break the normal flow. C should first return to B then A.

Any way i am having solution of your problem.
Register a broadcast receiver in A activity then from C send a broadcast to A. In A activity you can receive that broadcast and then clear the stack. This will automatically finish all child activities.

Override onbackpress and don't call super in onbackpress instead send a broadcast to activity A.

Answer (score 0):

- In activity B:

  public static boolean mDestroyActivity = false;
  @Override
      protected void onResume() {
          super.onResume();
          /**
           * exit when back from Activity C-> A (skip activity B)
           */
          Log.i("FINISH", "= " + mDestroyActivity);
          if (mDestroyActivity) {
              mDestroyActivity = false;
              finish();
          }
      }
- In activity C:

  B.mDestroyActivity = true;