# Android skip some intents in stack

Tags: android, android-intent, stack

I have read this post but it won't fix my problem. [Skip going back to direct parent activity when pressed back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202903/skip-going-back-to-direct-parent-activity-when-pressed-back)

Supposing I have a list of intents from A to Z, where A is the root. In any of these intents I would like to provide a "back to A" function, and the normal "back to previous" should stay. so how could I implement the "back to A" function?

Because A does lots of internet actions and is kinda slow, I don't want to new an A again, the best way would be to go in the stack and skip the intents in between and show A directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code from where you want to call the A which is in Stack.

```
Intent backToAIntent = new Intent(YourCurrentactivity.this,A.class);
backToAIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(backToAIntent);
```

This [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) will give you more info about your requirement.

Comment: I don't get this: I used the flag in code but when A is called, it still goes in onCreate, which is what I'm trying to avoid. any clue? I'm sure that A is in the stack.

Comment: add android:launchMode="singleInstance" to Activity A tag in androidmanifest file

Answer (score 0):

Start A activity with a special flag:

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
>
> If the activity being started is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it are destroyed and this intent is delivered to the resumed instance of the activity (now on top), through onNewIntent())