# return back and skip one activity android onbackpressed

Tags: android, android-activity, return, back, activity-finish

Here is my case
assuming that I have those activities
A -> B -> C -> D

I want to come back to A when the user click on the back button when he is in D
but also I want to come back to B when the user click on the back button of C

I thought to call finish when I go to C from B, but in this case I can't return to B if I click on back of C

how can I fix this issue without calling `onBackPressed` on two activities?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202903/skip-going-back-to-direct-parent-activity-when-pressed-back

Answer (score 0):

When you start each activity, you will need to use

```
startActivityForResult()
```

And then have a system of flags saying who is being stopped which are passed back. So, activity D:

```
timeToEnd() {
    setResult(RESULT_D_CLOSING);
    finish();
}
```

And then in A, C, D

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(resultCode)
    case RESULT_D_CLOSING:
        // Close on upwards
        setResult(RESULT_D_CLOSING);
        finish();
    case ....
        // You get the idea
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag in your intent (used to start "A" from "D")?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here. You can either start the activities with `startActivityForResult` and then `onBackPressed` of each activity pass a flag back that tells the activity to either exit of stay open.

An other option would be to implement A,B,C,D as fragments in the same activity put all the fragments on the backstack as you open them and then `onBackPress` you can programmatically loop through the backstack to see what you want to do.