# Skip activity onActivityResult isn’t called

Tags: java, android

I saw that someone already asked a similar question ([Skip going back to direct parent activity when pressed back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202903/skip-going-back-to-direct-parent-activity-when-pressed-back)) but not the same, so here is my situation.

There are 3 activities namely A , B , C and the invocation is in the following order : A -> B -> C. While in C,  I have to go back to A when an action occurs.

B and  C are started with the following code:

```
Intent target = new Intent(parent, B.class); //or C.class
 startActivityForResult(target, 1);
```

In C I will close the activity and go back to B with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("EXTRA", neededObject);
setResult(1, intent);
finish();
```

In B I’ve implemented the onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == 1) {
    setResult(1, data);
    finish();
}
```

No I’m expecting that A#onActivityResult will be called (I need the Extra-Intent-Data in the A#onActivityResult method). But it isn’t :-(

Here is my AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.C"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.B">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activities.Other"/>
    </activity>
```

Why the method isn’t called? Shall I implement it in another way?

It would be great if someone can help me.

Comment: How is defined your activity inside the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking result code? Also using the same request code is bad. Use different one for each activity

Comment: @Bojan I will not discuss the code example here this are only samples not the real code! Will it solve my problem if I change the result code?

Comment: @Elenasys: I've added it in my question

Comment: Your code looks okay to me. Post onActivityResult code of Activity A.

Comment: @DhavalPatel shall I? The method isn't called.

Comment: Which method isn't working onActivityResult  of Class A or onActivityResult  of Class B?

Comment: @DhavalPatel B#onActivityResult is called but A#onActivityResult not

Comment: Please post code of onActivityResult  of Class A. And please double check if  Activity B is starting with startActivityForResult or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your B activity's onActivityResult should be like below

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", message);
        setResult(1, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the different? I see only that you have created a new Intent,´but data is the original Itent from C.

Comment: the code i posted works fine on my side. Even, your code works fine, on my system !

Comment: @Dora.so A#onActivityResult is called?

Comment: Ok, I will try a quite simple testcase for my self

Comment: You're absolutley right, I 've found out that B hasn't started the activity with startActivityForResult B called startActivity after changing it, I is running.