# How to make Android app that redirects to another app upon opening?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'd like to address the issue of non customizable icons for apps on stock lockscreens (Verizon LG G4 in my case) by creating an app having an icon of my choosing that immediately opens another app (such as the phone or camera) when opened.  This app could then be selected for the lockscreen and simply function as a shortcut to the other app.

For the phone, it looks like I'll need something along the lines of:

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
startActivity(intent);`

But I'm not sure of where to put this within a Project so that it executes immediately, if it's even the right code, or if this is even a possibility.  Also, wondering what the code would look like for opening an app such as Firefox.

Note: I'm using Android Studio 1.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct.

There should not be any problem if you put it on the onCreate() method of the MainActivity, it will be excuted upon creation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It might also be useful to add `noHistory`. If the Activity is little more than a redirect.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202903/skip-going-back-to-direct-parent-activity-when-pressed-back

Comment: Thanks! I used the following code in MainActivity: 
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); 
startActivity(intent);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); } }`
and added `noHistory` to the Manifest for MainActivity. 

It works, but sometimes when clicking the App I can see a blank Activity page with the title of my App on the screen before it switches to the Phone Dial. I can live with it, but is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Figured out a workaround.  Ended up changing `extends AppCompatActivity` to `Activity` and then applied a transparent theme to MainActivity in the manifest.